# how to compare benchmarks in perl

Tags: perl

using the standard Benchmark module, I start to write some code like as usual, however I have one doubt: How can I compare two different versions of the same module?

For instance, I have a stable module version 1.0 and some parts may need some attention. So I decided to start write the version 1.1 in another branch and...

I can write a perl benchmark script that can output a series of [timethese](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark#timethese-(-COUNT,-CODEHASHREF,-%5B-STYLE-%5D-)) calls to compare different aspects of the code and run against both versions then check the output.

My question is... how can I compare two benchmark outputs? is there a benchmark diff tool?

I was checking around metacpan and find nothing to help me. And what google gives me is examples of benchmark using `cmpthese` but it compares two codes in the same codebase.

My other option is to create a `Package::Under::Test2` that is a copy of the original package and perform modifications and in the end I just substitute rename the package but it seems...  ugly

For instance, on golang we have the tool [benchstat](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/perf/cmd/benchstat) that can compare two benchmarks outputs and produce some statistics.

suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Run the benchmark twice with different settings for `@INC`. One run has the path for the old Perl module, and one run has the path for the new perl module.

```
$ perl -I/path/to/old benchmark.pl
$ perl -I/path/to/new benchmark.pl
```

You don't care so much about the percentages because you can look at the iterations per second.

But, unless it's a radically different implementation of the module, I wouldn't expect any significant differences between two minor versions of the same module. Remember that any difference of about 5% from Benchmark.pm is just benchmarking nois; that's why Dumbbench exists (and you should read Steffan's various posts about measurement theory).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than benchmarking, how about profiling? You know the changes you're making, so running the two versions through [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) will show you *in colour* what effect each line is having. It will help direct where you want to look for performance gains.

It's a fun module and easy to get started. Results are displayed in Web 1.0 html. I have found it a little addictive, so set yourself a halting condition to avoid chasing diminishing returns and adding unnecessary complexity.